# icon issue in android

Tags: android

i have developed one application in which getting ***install app information*** like name,package name, version,date, icon etc..
now i get all thing in proper manner, nut icon are store in   **"private Drawable icon;"** variable.
now i am drag `<imageview>` in main file and display those icon in this file so what i need to do?

Comment: Could not understand your question at all.

Comment: are you trying to display an icon using an imageView with a Drawable? is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: oke, i am explain. i have build one application in which get information of all install app. all information are correctly getting and now i go to display it(information like mention in question).so icon information also in variable right? so i want to display in layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could get the icon by calling the id?

```
Drawable icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
```

I hope, that I could helped you, but I don't really understand

Comment: no, i want this vice versa.
Means,icon variable has some value, that make icon and display in main layout through imageview.